# multi git account management with ssh key

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh

I have multiple Git accounts one is my personal use and one is for company use. Both accounts source need to be activated from my laptop.

**1st, I generated two ssh keys**:

```
% ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my@gmail.com" -f ~/.ssh/my
% ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "work@company.com" -f ~/.ssh/work
```

**2nd, use ssh-agent**

```
% eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

% ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/my
% ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/work
```

**3rd, Edit the SSH config**

touch `~/.ssh/config` and edit contents like below:

```
Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work

# account of myself, my@gmail.com
Host my
  HostName github.com
  User my
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my
  
# account of work, work@company.com  
Host work
  HostName github.com
  User work
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

**4th, Adding new SSH key to my GitHub account**

as the reference: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

**5th, Ensure the ssh-agent is running and loaded these two keys**

```
% ps -e | grep ssh-agent

% ssh-add -l

256 SHA256:RnbFaLfrSIX4Al134lkjaleiur1SMIz7+OFwx5I9RHVMewwo9eq my@gmail.com (ED25519)
```

**Now my question is :**
After I reboot the macOS, there is only one ssh key, I must activate another ssh key for work manually by the command below:

```
% ssh-add ~/.ssh/work

% ssh-add -l

256 SHA256:RnbFaLfrSIX4Al134lkjaleiur1SMIz7+OFwx5I9RHVMewwo9eq my@gmail.com (ED25519)
256 SHA256:QEWRrqpeowiufkndliuroqijr15u30491u3ojhjkrefaosdyflk work@company.com (ED25519)
```

and **I cannot switch to the work ssh key** when I working on the work repo (like ~/workcode), but I can found the `% git remove -v` response right, but got the wrong information when I run `% git push` as below:

```
ERROR: Permission to work/Test.git denied to my.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please tutor me how to switch to `my` or `work` ssh key when I working for myself or working for company.

Thank you.

Comment: The ssh account to use should be `git` in both cases: `User git`. As suggested in [the "testing" sction](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) of the docs: test your ssh configuration by running : `ssh my` / `ssh work`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can firstly revise the `~/.ssh/config` as below:

```
Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes

# account of my@gmail.com
Host mysec
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mysec
  
# account of work@company.com  
Host work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

and check the current ssh loaded by run `% ssh-add -l`
if you want to push code by private account or work account, you can run

`% ssh-add -D`

This will Deletes all identities from the agent. Then you can load the ssh key you want by:

`% ssh-add ~/.ssh/my` or `% ssh-add ~/.ssh/work`

there is only one ssh key effect even if you load the two ssh key, so please only load one ssh key for you push.

Answer (score 1):

The ssh account to use should be `git` in both cases: `User git`.

As suggested in [the "testing" sction](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) of the docs: test your ssh configuration by running : `ssh my` / `ssh work` (or `ssh git@my` / `ssh git@work` to explicitly pass the user account to connect with).

AFAIK, you don't need to explicitly load the keys in `ssh-agent` at startup, the first ssh connection will do that.

---

[edit] as suggested by @torek in the comments :

to avoid having ssh trying on its own *other* keys, you can also add  `IdentitiesOnly yes` to both config blocks.

Comment: It's also wise to add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to each of the two configurations, so that ssh doesn't try the "wrong" key first (or at all, really).